# Text video to dedicated short code to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, aws-pinpoint

Is there any service / functionality that allows someone to text a video to a dedicated number and that video gets uploaded to aws? The aws account and dedicated short code would be controlled by the same platform. This service would make it much easier to quickly upload videos from your phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no service that provides this as functionality.

You would need to code it yourself.

Comment: Thanks John. Do you know of any service to handle mms / iMessage data?

Comment: Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) can send SMS messages, but it does not support MMS. It also supports [Apple-style push notifications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/sending-push-notifications-to-ios-13-devices-with-amazon-sns/).

Comment: Thanks. I need inbound texts not SNS.

Comment: Twilio has a good service for SMS and MMS. However, videos sent as MMS are shrunken down to max 5mb.